# Gitlab : Auto Clone Repository to other location when new project created

Tags: git, gitlab

What I am trying to implement with my Gitlab Setup is, when new project is created by admin from Gitlab User Interface it will automatically clone the project to root directory of the apache where users can work and view the changes from browser rather than cloning the project to local system and push it to apache root directory.

I like to auto clone the new created gitlab project to be cloned at /var/www/html/

Comment: Doesn't gitlab already provide a repository browser?

Comment: What is meant is, while working on web application projects. I needed to clone the gitlab new created project automatically to web root directory so that apache could execute the files.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to leverage the API and the CI to do this sort of thing. The steps needed would be something like this:

1. Create a [System Hook](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/system_hooks/system_hooks.html) which triggers when a project is created.
2. If the hook occurs create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which defines the deployment on your webserver.
3. [Enable the runner](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html) for the project so deployment can take place.

Now everytime a push on the repository occurs it gets deployed on the webserver.

---

Example:

Create a System Hook via the Admin interface `Admin Area -> System Hooks` or with a `curl` command. [Doc](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/system_hooks.html#add-new-system-hook)

```
curl -X POST -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/hooks?url=https://gitlab.example.com/hook"
```

This will call the URL `https://gitlab.example.com/hook` whenever one of the following event happens:

`project_create, project_destroy, project_rename, project_transfer, user_add_to_team, user_remove_from_team, user_create, user_destroy, key_create, key_destroy, group_create, group_destroy, user_add_to_group, user_remove_from_group`

Now we need to create some sort of script which is run whenever `https://gitlab.example.com/hook` is called. This script either performs another `curl` request which creates a .gitlab-ci.yml file or uses git to automatically create the first commit. [Doc](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository)

```
curl -X POST -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' -F 'file_path=.gitlab-ci.yml' -F 'branch_name=master' -F 'commit_message=Initial' -F $'content=CI DEFINITION GOES HERE' 'https://gitlix.sw.jena.com/api/v3/projects/48/repository/files'
```

Then you need to enable a runner for this project so it deploys it to your webserver. [Doc](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/runners.html#enable-a-runner-in-project)

```
curl -X POST -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/9/runners" -F "runner_id=9"
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. This defines how I should work on getting things on flow for my requirement. I am at the very beginning with Gitlab and Hooks. Could you please elaborate further more how to create the specific system hook i been looking for to be triggered when new project is created. Thank You .

Comment: @CrshnaPariyar I updated the answer for more clarification.